# sql loader not loading all rows, while running from a Batch

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am trying to load a .data file to an SQL table using sql loader.

After loading :

Data file contains: 1287 records

Bad file Contains: 51 records

Table record Count: 640

CODE:

```
load data
infile 'c:\myfiles\Infile\daily_file.data' 
append
into table statement_list
fields terminated by ',' 
(account_number
,ammount
,transction_text
,merchant
,post_date
,transaction_date)
```

LOG:

```
SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Mon Apr 13 11:46:13 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.


Control File:   insert_data.ctl
Data File:      c:\myfiles\Infile\daily_file.data
Bad File:     daily_file.bad
Discard File:  none specified

(Allow all discards)

Number to load: ALL
Number to skip: 0
Errors allowed: 50
Bind array:     64 rows, maximum of 256000 bytes
Continuation:    none specified
Path used:      Conventional

Table STATEMENT_LIST, loaded from every logical record.
Insert option in effect for this table: APPEND

Column Name                  Position   Len  Term Encl Datatype
------------------------------ ---------- ----- ---- ---- ---------------------
ACCOUNT_NUMBER                      FIRST     *   |       CHARACTER            
TRANSACTION_SERNO                    NEXT     *   |       CHARACTER            
AMMOUNT                              NEXT     *   |       CHARACTER            
TRANSCTION_TEXT                      NEXT     *   |       CHARACTER            
MERCHANT                             NEXT     *   |       CHARACTER            
POST_DATE                            NEXT     *   |       CHARACTER            
TRANSACTION_DATE                     NEXT     *   |       CHARACTER            


Table STATEMENT_LIST:
851 Rows successfully loaded.
0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
0 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.


Space allocated for bind array:                 115584 bytes(64 rows)
Read   buffer bytes: 1048576

Total logical records skipped:          0
Total logical records read:           851
Total logical records rejected:         0
Total logical records discarded:        0

Run began on Mon Apr 13 11:46:13 2015
Run ended on Mon Apr 13 11:46:15 2015

Elapsed time was:     00:00:02.10
CPU time was:         00:00:00.10
```

It seems like there is some issue with Binding Parameters and Commit points in sql loader. This code was working fine before, after an restart of DB server, this error is occurring.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: The numbers you're reporting don't make sense given the log file you posted.  I suppose it's possible that you've encountered a major bug in SQL*Loader.  If you feel that to be the case, open a support request with Oracle.  Much more likely, though, is that however you are looking at the wrong data file/ table/ bad file.

Comment: You have a maximum number of errors of 50 (the default), which is why it's stopping - I'm assuming that either your control file, table DDL are incorrect or that the file you're loading doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: It should should the errors for the failed 51 records. It stops at 51 because by default the "errors=" flag is set to 50. Can you see what is being writen to stderr? Is there no ORA-nnnn or SQLLDR-nnnn type error codes/message?

Comment: @Ben This issue was with Data formats, I changed some data format hence the issue got resolved.